# Alfresco OpenAM integration needed with a Realm in login url

Tags: alfresco, openam

Most of the things written in https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/authentication-ldap-sso/sso-openam-06052012
is enough for me to setup but it is just the part of it.

I am using a realm in Open AM and I want the redirect to be using the realm.

I have changed the properties in OpenSSOAgentBootstrap.properties to reflect the realm

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.organization.name = /LdapRealm
```

and the OpenSSOAgentConfiguration.properties are changed as below

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url[0]=http://verify.organisation.com:8080/OpenAM/XUI/#login/&realm=LdapRealm
```

but the problem is when the real redirection happens then the url does not consider realm ( I have tried ?realm=LdapRealm too / but in liferay server the above URL is able to direct)

The following is what i am getting the redirection as (see there is no realm showing up)

http://verify.organisation.com:8080/OpenAM/XUI/#login/&goto=http%3A%2F%2Falfresco.organisation.com%3A8080%2Fshare%2Fpage%2F

Also the cookie user is not setting correctly to the user i logged in with thus getting 403 too

Which are the other properties i need to look at .

---------------- Added later ----------------

Strangly even if i manually change the url to

```
http://verify.wipro.com:8080/OpenAM/XUI/#login/&realm=LdapRealm&goto=http%3A%2F%2Falfresco.oraganisation.com%3A8080%2Fshare%2Fpage%2F
```

I am getting the following error in debug.out/ I also tried options /OpenAM/UI/Login?realm=LdapRealm but it is auto redirected to http://verify.wipro.com:8080/OpenAM/XUI/#login/&realm=LdapRealm

error reads as below

```
    amWebPolicy:03/24/2015 06:45:46:323 AM UTC: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-7,5,main]
ERROR: AmWebPolicy: Unable to check policy for resource: http://alfresco.organisation.com:8080/share/page/, action: GET; Access will be denied
com.sun.identity.policy.remote.PolicyEvaluationException: Server reported Exception, serverMessage=Evaluation error.
Unable to retrieve application under realm /.
Unable to retrieve application under realm /.
        at com.sun.identity.policy.client.ResourceResultCache.getResultsFromServer(ResourceResultCache.java:745)
        at com.sun.identity.policy.client.ResourceResultCache.getResourceResults(ResourceResultCache.java:563)
        at com.sun.identity.policy.client.ResourceResultCache.getPolicyDecision(ResourceResultCache.java:345)
        at com.sun.identity.policy.client.ResourceResultCache.getPolicyDecision(ResourceResultCache.java:250)
        at com.sun.identity.policy.client.PolicyEvaluator.getPolicyDecision(PolicyEvaluator.java:403)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.policy.AmWebPolicy.checkPolicyForResource(AmWebPolicy.java:143)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.URLPolicyTaskHandler.process(URLPolicyTaskHandler.java:122)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilter.processTaskHandlers(AmFilter.java:194)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilter.isAccessAllowed(AmFilter.java:157)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentBaseFilter.doFilter(AmAgentBaseFilter.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

somewhere down the line it is giving a feeling that Alfresco is built for root realm. May be Some development is needed to get any other realm working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to configure the login.url to still point to the legacy UI (i.e. /OpenAM/UI/Login?realm=/LdapRealm), as there is a very special filter in front of that endpoint (when XUI is enabled) that redirects incoming requests to the correct XUI endpoints.

Unfortunately currently the agents are not able to work with login URLs that have # characters in them, which means that the agents will construct invalid URLs that have ? after #. Possibly this is the root cause of your issue.

Comment: With the changes the URL redirection still did not work. Looks like it getting cached from somewhere.

Comment: in the logs i am getting erro which is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723466/openam-agent-for-tomcat-can-not-read-authservice-url Looks like i can igonore it. but it seems like the version can be a issue too. I am using the j2ee tomcat agent version 3.5 & OpenAM 12

Comment: In case there is a any suggestion to delete the cache, I can give it a try . Any other suggestions are welcome. I will give a try and see if it works.

Comment: I checked the agentapp application and all other folders in j2ee agent but could not locate the cache folder location. Probably using root realm is good option

Comment: I suppose you are aware that modifying the OpenSSOAgentConfiguration.properties does not have any effect in case your agent profile is "centralized" (which is the default). You should probably update the agent profile in the OpenAM console (Access Control - realm - Agents - Web/J2EE).

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will give it a try. but what it will be it is something like somemachine:port/agentapp

Comment: Good one Peter. It is centralized indeed. and I can give the login url in OpenAM Agent. I need to validate and confirm